# Do you know a Haskell package for dirent.h on Windows?

Tags: haskell, cabal, hackage, dirent.h

Do you know a Haskell package for dirent.h on Windows?

There is similar set of functions in system.posix but those functions are not implemented on Windows.
I wonder if there is similar somewhere else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

???

`dirent.h` is a C library header. If you want to traverse directories, use [System.Directory.getDirectoryContents](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/directory/1.0.0.3/doc/html/System-Directory.html#v%3AgetDirectoryContents). This API should work on Windows.